# strophe addHandler won't work

Tags: jquery, xmpp, strophe

addHandler after calling connect and before and neither inside the connection handler won't catch any messages from the server, anyone knows whats this is about?

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://example.org:7070/http-bind/');
conn.addHandler(function(iq){
console.log(iq);
return true;
}, null, 'message','event', null, 'pubsub.example.org', null);

conn.connect('nick13@example.org', 'password', function(status, err_cond){




if(status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED)
{

$(document).trigger('connected');
}
else if(status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED)
{
$(document).trigger('disconnected '+err_cond);
}
else if(status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING)
{
alert('CONNECTING '+err_cond);
}
else if(status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING)
{
alert('DISCONNECTING '+ err_cond);
}
$(document).bind('connected',function(){
alert('CONNECTED');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem with your addHandler() parameters:

`'event'` is not an XMPP message type. I recommend leaving it as null (matches all types), or check to see what your pubsub component uses (it will be 'normal' or 'headline', and may be configurable).